# Adding a legend to a ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I try to add a legend to my ggplot2 plots but it is not working out. Also the command show.legend does not change anything

Following the answer of this question ([Adding manual legend in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490043/adding-manual-legend-in-ggplot)) I tried scal_colour_manueal but it did not work out

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

color1 = "#D30F4B"
color2 = "#66B512"

data= data.frame(Week = rep(1:5,2), kpi = rep(c("Var1", "Var2"), each=5), value = runif(10), value2 = c(runif(5), rep(NA,5))  )

ggp <- ggplot( data = data, aes( x = Week, y = value, group = kpi) ) +
  geom_line(color=color1, show.legend = T) 

ggp <- ggp +
geom_line( mapping = aes( x = Week, y = value2, group = kpi), colour = color2 , show.legend = T) 

ggp <- ggp +  
  facet_wrap( kpi ~ . , ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c(color1, color2))

plot(ggp)
```

How can I add a legend to this plot?

Comment: That's almost what I am, looking for but it is only showing the legend for one of the lines. Not for both.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. You should turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't set colours outside of aes if you want them to depent on some variable of the data frame.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

color1 = "#D30F4B"
color2 = "#66B512"

data= data.frame(Week = rep(1:5,2), kpi = rep(c("Var1", "Var2"), each=5), value = runif(10), value2 = c(runif(5), rep(NA,5))  )

ggp <- ggplot( data = data, aes( x = Week, y = value, col= kpi) ) +
  geom_line(show.legend = T) 

ggp <- ggp +
geom_line( mapping = aes( x = Week, y = value2, col= kpi), show.legend = T) 

ggp <- ggp +  
  facet_wrap( kpi ~ . , ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c(color1, color2))

plot(ggp)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the fast support. Could you maybe also tell me what I had to do if I want the two lines (value and value2) in the first plot to be shown in two different colors?

Comment: @NashVio: You could do something like `data <- gather(data, variable, values, value:value2, factor_key=TRUE); data$kpi_variable <- factor(paste0(data$kpi, data$variable)); 
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Week, y = values, col= kpi_variable )) +
  geom_line()`. This gives you one plot with three lines in different colors.

Answer (score 3):

Another hint: ggplot works best, when data is "tidy" (see e.g. Hadley Wickham's [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)). Then solution could look like this (the `gather`-call reshapes / tidies the data so that it suits better to ggplot):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

color1 = "#D30F4B"
color2 = "#66B512"

data= data.frame(Week = rep(1:5,2), kpi = rep(c("Var1", "Var2"), each=5), value = runif(10), value2 = c(runif(5), rep(NA,5))  )

data <- gather(data, key = value_name, value = value, -Week, -kpi) ## tidy the data with "gahter"

ggplot(data, aes(x = Week, y = value, colour = value_name, group = value_name)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(kpi ~ ., ncol = 1) +
    scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c(color1, color2))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could have two `geom_line` with their respective colors and then use `facet_wrap`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data) + 
  aes(x = Week, y = value2, group = kpi, colour = color2) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes( x = Week, y = value, group = kpi, color = color1)) + 
  facet_wrap( kpi ~ . , ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values=c(color1, color2))
```

[image]